# IEEE bibliography style for BibLaTeX (not BibTeX)?

Tags: latex, bibliography, ieee, biblatex

Does anyone have or know where to find o bibliography style file like IEEEtr or IEEEtran for BibLaTeX? I've been searching all over, but could only find the ones for BibTeX. BibTeX can't really do the things I want, but my thesis has to conform with the IEEE standards...

I'd be really thankful if anyone could give me a hint how to use IEEE styles with BibLaTeX

Thanks a lot, Simon

Comment: What is bibtex not able to do that you want and biblatex able to do?

Comment: @vpit3833 - for example, biblatex allows you to include your .bib file contents inline in the latex file.. But indeed, its manual, while stating that it interfaces with bibtex - it makes no mention of whether bibtex styles can be used, it just says:"_\bibliographystyle is
omitted entirely (all features are controlled by package options)_".

Comment: This question was posted over on tex.stackexchange.com recently, and a `biblatex-ieee` style is in the works: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10727/ieee-and-aip-bibliography-styles-in-biblatex

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more relevant to tex.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 7):

Good news,

[biblatex-ieee](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ieee?lang=en) was released (Feb/12) by Joseph Wright. See at http://www.mail-archive.com/ctan-ann@dante.de/msg03710.html

Greetings!

JF

Answer (score 3):

```
\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
```

see [Ieee style files for biblatex.](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/biblatex-ieee.html)

Comment: The link is down.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm interested in the same thing - and I guess the answer is, `biblatex` can NOT use the style files that `bibtex`, like `ieeetr.bst`. The reason I think that is:

[Re: Biblatex: "patent" record type](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2007-01/msg00179.html)

> I'm currently working on **porting** a BibTeX style for my subject area
>   (chemistry) to biblatex.

[CTAN: directory: /tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/)

> biblatex-apa/
>   biblatex-chem/
>   biblatex-chicago/

... that is - apparently you have to build your own `biblatex` style, if you want to to be the same as a `bibtex` style.